# SpringMVC how to return a .doc file (from a jsp page)?

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc

I'm trying to map a request for a "fake" MSWord file: the file is an html page actually, with a .doc extension to force the user to download it and open it with MS Word.

The source file `/app/report.jsp` is populated and shown as an HTML page if the mapped URL does not contains a `.doc` extension, but if I add the extension all the `<jsp:include />` in the jsp file  stop working, and at the same time the file is still rendered as a html document.

**How can I force the user to download the file as a Word document?**

Here is the method mapping the URL, from my controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/report.doc", produces = "application/msword")
    public ModelAndView reportProducer(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
        mav.addObject("something", false);
        mav.setViewName("/app/report");
        response.setContentType("application/msword"); // probably unnecessary?
        return mav;
    }
```

here is the *web.xml* file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd"
     id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">

<display-name>MyApp</display-name>

 <listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    </listener-class>
</listener>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>

<error-page>
    <error-code>500</error-code>
    <location>/WEB-INF/classes/jsp/app/errorPage.jsp</location>
</error-page>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/static/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>springmvc</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>springmvc</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

and here is my *applicationContext.xml* file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

<mvc:annotation-driven/>
<mvc:view-controller path="/" view-name="home"/>

<context:annotation-config/>
<context:component-scan base-package="myBasePackage1, myBasePackage2"/>

[... datasources, beans omitted ...]

<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"/>
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/classes/jsp/"/>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
</bean>

</beans>
```

---

**EDIT**

The issue with the incomplete parsing of the page (not including *.jspf parts) is related to a change I did while trying to solve the issue. I removed the following code from `web.xml`. When restored, everything worked as expected:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>jsp</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jspf</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: If you're returning a view name, you're expecting the contents of the corresponding JSP to be the entire response.

Comment: I don't understand how JSP includes could fail just because the request has been forwarded from a controller mapped to a .doc URL. What is the code of the JSP? The JSP should have `<%@ page contentType="application/msword" %>`

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Indeed, I expect the corresponding JSP to be the entire response. The "includes" does not get included, unfortunately, but only if there is a ".doc" extension in the RequestMapping annotation value

Comment: @JBNizet you are correct, if the page contentType is "application/msword" the page became a downloadable file, and word opens it correctly. It's difficult to provide you the entire page/includes because of their size,  but I can say that all the JSTL/EL code get rendered correctly, only `<jsp:include page="/WEB-INF/classes/jspf/report/details.jspf"/>` -like code does not get parsed if the file extension is .doc. This is weird.

Comment: @JBNizet BTW you answered to my main question, so if you'd like to add an answer I'd be glad to accept it :)

Comment: jsp files shouldn't be under WEB-INF/classes. And jspf files are supposed to be included statically, not dynamically.

Comment: @JBNizet you are right, and please forgive my noobness but it's my first java webapp :) however, I've solved the issue of the jspf "not included", I've edited my question. Thanks for your help, please do not forget to add your comment about the `<@page contentType` as an answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jspf files are normally JSP fragments, that are supposed to be included statically, not dynamically. I wouldn't use that standard file extension for regular JSPs. Just use the .jsp extension. That would make your custom jsp servlet mapping unnecessary, and would be less confusing.

WEB-INF/classes is for classes and resources loaded by the class loader. JSPs shouldn't be located there. I would put them anywhere else under WEB-INF.

Finally, regarding the rendering as a web page, that is because the default content type set by JSPs is text/html. You need to add

```
<%@ page contentType="application/msword" %>
```

at the top of your JSP to set the appropriate content type.